# I want to receive username through get method and Post the data to itself and update the database

Tags: javascript, php

This code gets the password from below form I want it to fetch the username as well but the code is incapable to send it.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['password'])){
$usernamea = $_POST['username'];
$pas=$_POST['password'];
require('dbcoonect.php');
$sqla="UPDATE student SET password='$pas' WHERE username='$usernamea'";
if(mysqli_query($conn,$sqla)){
 $out = '<h1>The form was submitted</h1>';
 }    
}
```

this code is the continuation of the above part

```
 else{
//get the name through get method
$uska=$_GET['username'];

 //make a form to post the data  **`along with the username`**
 //this is the code which post the data to the above if statement 
    $out = "
<form method='POST' id='form_id'>
<input type='hidden' name='username' value='$uska'>
    <input type='password' id='con' name='conpass' >
    <input type='password' id='lan' value='' name='password' onblur='fun()' >
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function fun(){

        document.forms['form_id'].submit();

}
      </script>
";
}
echo $out;

?>
```

Comment: Maybe `value=''` on `name='username'`is your issue? You also are open to SQL injections and should be hashing passwords. You also are open to XSS injections.

Comment: sorry that was by mistake while typing here but  that's not the issue in the program

Comment: Okay, so what does happen? Where does this fail?

Comment: it gets the username through the get method but failed to set the value of the hidden field

Comment: Where do the get for the username comes from? Can you show also the URL sending it?

Comment: Please post only relevant code. If the issue is before the mysql interactions that part is irrelevant. So your generated source is `<input type='hidden' name='username' value=''>`?

Comment: there are no error in the database interaction and the url through which the username comes is  " h.php?username='$user' " and this too works fine

Comment: @MohitShah, error is in his form code. The form is written in pure html which is inside php code chunk. So, if the form code is outside php code chunk in his main project, then the error might come from the side that he did not echo the username in html form (if he really puts html outside php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$out = "
<form method='POST' id='form_id'>
<input type='hidden' name='username' value='$uska'>
    <input type='password' id='con' name='conpass' >
    <input type='password' id='lan' value='' name='password' onblur='fun()' >
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function fun(){

        document.forms['form_id'].submit();

}
      </script>
";
```

In second part of your code chunk, you start with PHP by typing `else{` but after `$out=''`, you go through html from `<form method....` to `</script>`. You can't place a pure HTML code inside a PHP code. Either you have to echo the HTML part inside PHP code chunk or you have to close php chunk by `?>`, start html and after html code chunk again start php code chunk by `<?php`. Again, after html, I can see a `'';`, perhaps that is the missing part/semicolon of `$out=''`.

Anyway, if it is typing mistake here, I assume you have placed form in HTML in your main code. If it is, then you have to echo the username like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='username' value='<?php echo $uska; ?>'>
```

Comment: Typos should be addressed in comments. This wasn't the issue. `conpass` is probably a confirm password field.

Comment: The user did not tell about typos before submitting my reply. After submitting or during submitting my reply, the user edited his question. Until the user did clear that is was typos, it may be the cause of the issue. So, I replied it in comment. Anyway I found new issue and corrected my answer too.